# Microsoft Access SQL Sub-Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to use a sub-query to list the module code, room code, day and time for all lectures involving a lecturer called "Josephine Griffith" in my database but I can't get it to work.

The SQL Query I am trying is

```
SELECT moduleCode, roomCode, dayReq, timeReq
FROM roomBooking
WHERE moduleCode
(SELECT mCode
FROM modLect
WHERE lecturer = "Josephine Griffith");
```

When I execute this, I get

> At most one record can be returned by this subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the `IN` keyword

```
SELECT moduleCode, roomCode, dayReq, timeReq
FROM roomBooking
WHERE moduleCode IN
(
  SELECT mCode
  FROM modLect
  WHERE lecturer = 'Josephine Griffith'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you have posted is not correct, you're missing an operator.

Probably you're using = but if the subquery returns more than 1 row, you should use IN

```
SELECT moduleCode, roomCode, dayReq, timeReq
FROM roomBooking
WHERE moduleCode IN (SELECT mCode
                     FROM modLect
                     WHERE lecturer = 'Josephine Griffits')
```

But, I think you could also use a join instead of a subquery

```
SELECT modulecode, roomcode, dayReq, timeReq
FROM roomBooking, modLect 
WHERE roomBooking.moduleCode = modLect.mCode
  AND lecturer = 'Josephine Griffits'
```